# Congruence of triangles: SSA criteria

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, congruences-geometry

It is well known that this criteria does not work in general. I am trying to answer to the following question

if two triangles have two sides and the angle NOT between them equal, they are either congruent or..?

In other words, does it have a name when two triangles meet SSA but they are not equal?

Comment: Hint: try constructing a triangle with the lengths of two sides and an angle not contained in them as the givens...

Comment: I have done that already, but I can't see what it is. Maybe I am missing a definition.

Comment: Can't find anything angle or area related, can you guide me a bit?

Comment: The word is *incongruent* :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is either congruence or not.
 I can disprove $SSA$ congruence.

In $\triangle ABC $ and $\triangle DEF$,

let,$AB=DE$ , $BC=EF$ and $\angle BCA=\angle EFD$.[image]

this condition does not say about $\angle  B$ and $\angle E $
 so, this condition does not work

see the visual disproof of $SSA$

[image]